# Mongoose: How to get N random documents, then another N random documents without duplicates from previous batch

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get N random documents from my collection, and then another N random documents without duplicates for every subsequent batches.  I was able to use the following aggregation to get my first batch of documents, but I am not too sure on what to do afterwards.

```
const aggregate = Model.aggregate([{ $sample: { size } }]);
```

Now I was thinking that I have to use a cursor?  Not too sure how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use some code:

(I see you use `mongoose` so i'm writing this with `mongoose` syntax)

```
const aggregate = Model.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: size } }]);

const aggregate2 = Model.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: {$nin: aggregated.map(val => val._id)}}},
    { $sample: { size: size } }
]);
```

Notice this required the second pipeline to first `$match` the entire collection minus the sample data amount. this could be very inefficient.

Depending on your scale I recommend adding some heuristics like lets assume sample size is `x` and we have `y` documents in db.

I would use something like the follow pipeline:

```
const aggregate = Model.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: x } }]);

const aggregate2 = Model.aggregate([
    { $sample: { size: 2x } }
    { $match: { _id: {$nin: aggregated.map(val => val._id)}}},
    { $limit: x }
]);
```

You can tinker the numbers (2x is upper limit but depending on the size of your dataset it could be lowered with high probability for success), This will allow you to receive x unique documents in the second pipeline as well while utilising the `$sample` index fetching.

This is all assuming you qualify for [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) conditions for index usage:

> $sample is the first stage of the pipeline
>
> N is less than 5% of the total documents in the collection
>
> The collection contains more than 100 documents